# Downloading an audio file from server using a 'circular progress' with a particular position

Tags: android

I have created a music app with websrvice data. I get all data from a webservice and set it to listview and now I want to download the audio and store it in the sdcard.

I want to click on the download imageview and I want that imagview to change to a progressbar tand the file downloads. After file has downloaded I want the  image to change but it is not.

How do I solve the problem?

```
public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> 
{
        Context context;

        private static final int MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;
        AudioRecyleviewAdapter.DownloadTask downloadTask;
        String Name;
        ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
        ProgressBar progressBar;
        ImageView imgdowload;
        int position;

        public DownloadTask(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading....");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);

            mProgressDialog.show();

            mProgressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {

                    String sdcard_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
                    File file = new File(sdcard_path + "/Petli Satsang/" + Name + ".mp3");
                    file.delete();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Download In Background", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... str) {

            String URL = str[0];
            Name = str[1];
            InputStream input = null;
            OutputStream output = null;
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            try {
                java.net.URL url = new URL(URL);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    return "Server returned HTTP " + connection.getResponseCode()
                            + " " + connection.getResponseMessage();
                }
                int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();
                input = connection.getInputStream();
                String sdcard_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
                File PapersDiractory = new File(sdcard_path + "/Petli Satsang/");
                PapersDiractory.mkdirs();
                File outputFile = new File(PapersDiractory, "" + Name);
                output = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

                byte data[] = new byte[MEGABYTE];
                long total = 0;
                int count;
                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                    if (isCancelled()) {
                        input.close();
                        return null;
                    }
                    total += count;
                    if (fileLength > 0) // only if total length is known
                        publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
                    int progress = (int) (total * 100 / fileLength);
                    Log.d("Progress = ", "" + (int) (total * 100 / fileLength));
                    output.write(data, 0, count);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return e.toString();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (output != null)
                        output.close();
                    if (input != null)
                        input.close();
                } catch (IOException ignored) {
                }

                if (connection != null)
                    connection.disconnect();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
            // if we get here, length is known, now set indeterminate to false
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
            mProgressDialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
            //progressBar.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(progress[0])));

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            if (result != null)
                Toast.makeText(context, "Download error: " + result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else {
                int position = 0;
                Toast.makeText(context, "File downloaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

//code to call function on dowload image cilck

```
 holder.download.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                File extStore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                final File myFile = new File(extStore.getAbsolutePath() + "/Petli Satsang/" + detail.getTitle() + ".mp3");
                if (!myFile.exists()) {
                    if (isOnline()) {
                        DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask(context);
                        downloadTask.execute(Constant.ImagePath_audio1 + detail.getPath(), "" + detail.getTitle() + ".mp3");
                    } else {
                        try {
                            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
                            alertDialog.setTitle("Info");
                            alertDialog.setMessage("Internet not available, Cross check your internet connectivity and try again");
                            alertDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
                            alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });
                            alertDialog.show();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            //Log.d(Constants.TAG, "Show Dialog: " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "File already Exists in " + myFile, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass your view to AsyncTask with setter getter or constructor in AsyncTask

```
    this.clickedRowView = clickedRowView;
    public DownloadTask(Context context,View clickedRowView) {
        this.context = context;
        this.clickedRowView = clickedRowView;
    }
```

Call your DownloadTask inside onclick like

```
//v comes from onClick method which points to holder.download view.
DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask(context,v);
v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);//make Image View invisible and display progressbar

((RelativeLayout)v.getParent()).findViewById(R.id.progressBar).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);// make progressbar to visible
```

Now you hold your view into the asynctask, now you should change your image view after download successes or fails

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        clickedImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ((RelativeLayout)v.getParent()).findViewById(R.id.progressBar).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);// make progressbar to invisible **EDIT 1**
        if (result != null)
            Toast.makeText(context, "Download error: " + result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else {
            int position = 0;
            Toast.makeText(context, "File downloaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if(clickedRowView != null){
             //You can reach your holder view in here! if this is image view just set image with ((ImageView)clickedRowView).setImageBitmap(...); etc..
        }
    }
```

**EDIT 1 :** 
If you want to make your Image View invisible and make Progress Bar visible, you should put them into same ViewGroup and setVisibility to right state. 
And change xml file which holds ImageView like this:

```
<RelativeLayout 
  android:id="@+id/imageAndProgressContainer"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"/>
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: now my question i click download image hide downlaod image and visible circle progressbar of that postion .

Comment: but onprogress update i cant set progress on progressbar

Comment: If you reach your progressbar when user clicks image view, you should be able to update it on onprogress